# grails: keep list order when using findAllBy

Tags: list, grails, findall

I want to keep the order of my first list

```
def myList = [444,1111,33333,22222]
```

But when I use `findAllBy` the order is changed

```
def myList2 = myDomain.findAllByRmIdInList(myList)
```

=> out : [1111, 22222, 33333, 444]

There is a way to desactivate order by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the order of your list, you can use the dynamic finder 'getAll()' (here is the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getAll.html))

> Retrieves a List of instances of the domain class for the specified
>   ids, ordered by the original ids list. If some of the provided ids are
>   null or there are no instances with these ids, the resulting List will
>   have null values in those positions.

So you could try the next code:

```
def myList2 = myDomain.getAll(myList)
```

**UPDATED AFTER COMMENTS**

You can use a Comparator for that. It is a little bit more tricky, but it should work. Below you'll find an example:

```
def myList = [444,1111,33333,22222]
def mc = [compare: { a,b -> a.rmId == b.rmId ? 0 : myList.indexOf(a.rmId) < myList.indexOf(b.rmId) ? -1 : 1 } ] as Comparator
def myList2 = myDomain.findAllByRmIdInList(myList)
def results = myList2.sort(mc) 

results.each() {
    log.info(it.rmId)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As specified in the documentation I need to have ids, but in my case I don't have them. I can get ids for all my elements, one by one, but I want to avoid that (I will do that if I don't have the choice).

Comment: Hi Jils. Sorry for the first answer, I didn't see the 'rm' before 'id' in your dynamic finder. I just updated my answer with a comparator. It should work.

Comment: Thanks its work.
Can I have some explanation of your seconde line?

Comment: You're welcome. The second line is a "Comparator". It is a new rule to sort your list. 'a' and 'b' are two elements of your findAll(), so they belong to 'myDomain'. If a.rmId == b.rmId, then I suppose that a == b (-> 0). If the position of a.rmId in myList is lower than the position of b.rmId in MyList, then 'a' has to appear before 'b' in the result (-> -1). If the position of a.rmId in myList is greater than the position of b.rmId in myList, then 'a' will appear after 'b' (-> 1).

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
def myList2 = MyDomain.findAllByRmIdInList(myList, [sort:"pmId"])
```

if you want you can also pass order either "desc" or "asc"

Note: finders works on Domain not on controllers.

Comment: I added `[sort:"prop"]` and I have the following error:
could not resolve property: prop of: app.myDomain.

Comment: In place of "prop" write your domain property on which you want to sort.

Comment: As I wrote I don't want to do a sort, I want to keep the order of my first list. Maybe my question is not clear...

Comment: Did you have overridden your toString() ?

Comment: toString() in the Domain? yes I did.

Comment: Post your toString() method.

Comment: `String toString(){ return "${pmId}" }`